# Links to other tab bar view from uiwebview

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uiwebview, hyperlink, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar iphone app. The second tab has formatted text with images so I inserted it as html file to uiwebview. I would like insert links on some parts of the text and on some images in this html file to the first tab view with different parameters. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of UIWebViewDelegate,and implement the method:

```
"webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:

Sent before a web view begins loading content."
```

...and implement your code to do things on the first tab when the user clicks any of the "special" links. Also, make sure to return "false" when the link clicked is one of those links, to stop the webview from loading them in the second tab.